Que input type='week' no salte a la siguiente linea
tengo un formulario en el cual uso un input type=week, lo que pasa es que empieza la semana en domingo hasta el sábado, pero selecciona de lunes a domingo, y quisiera o que seleccionara de domingo a sábado o bien que se ordenara de lunes a domingo, no sé si me explique bien pero dejaré imágenes de referencia, esta muestra como quiero que quede
esta muestra como queda actualmente:

De igual forma dejo un fragmento de html:


 Fecha:
            <input type="week" style="width: auto; height:40px; width:14%; border-radius: 5px; border: solid 1px; border-color: gray" name="fecha" id="fecha">




Eso depende exclusivamente de la configuración del sistema. Tú, en tu computador lo tienes configurado así, por eso se ve de esa forma

Y no hay manera de mandar una configuracion por defecto del input?
